# Loop through the services array and ask the user which services they want for their <insert model>

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Here are my instructions:
In main, ask the user what make of automobile they own.  Store this data in a string.

- Your first method should take the make via parameter and present the user with the following greeting: Hello!  We will be happy to service your  automobile today!
- Write a second method named carMaintenance.  It should take in the make via parameter and return the price to Main.

o   Create two local arrays: services and prices.
§  One will hold these strings: Oil Change, Tire Rotation, Air Filter, Check Fluids
§  The second will hold these doubles: 39.99, 49.99, 19.99, 10.99
o   Loop through the services array and ask the user which services he wants for his .  Make sure you display the price along with the service.  Use an accumulator to total the price for all requested services, using the prices array.
o   Return the price to Main.

- Write a third method name finalPrice that takes in the price from Main.

o   First, tack on 30% for labor to the price.
o   Then, ask if the car is an import.  If the answer is yes, add another 5% to the price.
o   Add 7% sales tax.
o   Display the total price to the user from this method.

Method 1 is done, however method 2 I need help with the loop and I was wondering if I can get some assistance on it. Since it's only asking me the model and then greeting me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class autoRepairShop {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); //Scanner Object
    String automobileMake;
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Input your automobile model/make: ");
    String model = input.next();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Hello! We will be happy to service your " + model + " automobile today!");

}

/** Method 2 **/
static void carMaintenance() {
    String[] services = new String[3];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    double[] prices = new double[3];
    String str;

    services[0] = "Oil Change";
    services[1] = "Tire Rotation";
    services[2] = "Air Filter";
    services[3] = "Check Fluids";

    prices[0] = 39.99;
    prices[1] = 49.99; 
    prices[2] = 19.99; 
    prices[3] = 10.99; 

    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
        String model = null;
        System.out.println("which services do you want for your " + model);
        String services1 = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Your choices are");
        for(String services + double prices = 0; );
    }
};
```

}

Comment: Stack Overflow is not here to complete your homework for you. Show us what you've done, and where *specifically* you're getting stuck. As it currently is posted, there doesn't appear to be any effort to solve for several of the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

A. Your arrays should be initialized to size 4 ([4]), as each array has 4 elements. As it is, you are going to get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException's on each arr[3] = ...; Also, it would be cleaner and safer to initialize your arrays like `String services[] = ['A','B','C','D'];`

B. For your loop, you want to move the printlns in the loop outside before the loop

```
System.out.println("Enter your model");
String model = input.nextLine();
```

It isn't clear how model fits in with what you are doing and how you are intending to use it, but I've left this in here, as it was in your original code

```
System.out.println("which services do you want for your " + model);
System.out.println("Your choices are");

for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
    System.out.println(services[i] + ": " + prices[i]);
}
String services1 = input.nextLine();
```

Also you should create a constant (final) variable somewhere to indicate how many services and prices you have, and you should reference that variable in your loop iteration